# Couchbase N1qlQuery: delete cause error to the query service

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I try to run this query

```
 delete from bucket o
 use keys (select raw ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(d, t), s), u)
 from bucket
 use keys 'SS')
```

I get this response:

```
 {
    "status": "Unexpected server error"
 }
```

in the server log I see this:

```
 Service 'query' exited with status 1. Restarting. Messages: runtime.goexit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1 fp=0xc20e97cfc0 sp=0xc20e97cfb8
created by github.com/couchbase/query/parser/n1ql.NewLexerWithInit
/home/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/watson-unix/goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/query/parser/n1ql/n1ql.nn.go:30999 +0x4a6c9
[goport] 2016/11/29 08:40:11 /opt/couchbase/bin/cbq-engine terminated: signal: aborted (core dumped)
```

What the problem with this query?

I am using couchbase version 4.5.

Comment: What version of Couchbase are you using?

Comment: @geraldss couchbase version 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use ARRAY_FLATTEN() function or the FIRST operator.

delete from bucket o use keys 
ARRAY_FLATTEN( ***(*** select raw ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(d, t), s), u) from bucket use keys 'SS'***)***, 1)
returning meta(o).id;

or

delete from bucket o
use keys FIRST x FOR x IN 
            ***(*** select raw ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(d, t), s), u)
             from bucket
             use keys 'SS' ***)*** 
         END
returning meta(o).id;

Note that parenthesis (in bold italics) is required around the sub-query when it is used as expression (for example, as parameter to ARRAY_FLATTEN() or in the FIRST construct)

Answer (score 0):

USE KEYS requires array of keys. ARRAY_CONCAT() returns array and Subquery returns array. It become array of array.

Remove one of the array as follows.

delete from bucket o
 use keys (select raw ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY_CONCAT(d, t), s), u)
 from bucket
 use keys 'SS')[0];

If the ARRAY_CONCAT() argument is missing or null, it may return same panic error in 4.5. This has been fixed in 4.5.1.